# Regarding homotopy and proper maps

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f:R^n\to R^n$ be a smooth, proper map where $n\geq 2$.

(a). Prove that $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} |f(x)|=\infty$ (i.e. for all $R>0$, there is $r>0$ such that if $|x|>r$ then $|f(x)|>R$).

(b). From (a) it follows that there is $r_0>0$ such that for all $x\in R^n$ that satisfy $|x|>r_0$: $f(x)\neq 0$.
Let $r_0$ be such a number.

For all $r\geq r_0$ define a map:

$\phi_r:S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$
by

$$\phi_r(x)=\frac{f(rx)}{\|f(rx)\|}$$

Prove that deg $\phi_r$ is independent of the choice of r.

(c). In part (b) symbols, assume that deg $\phi_r\neq 0$.
Prove that $f$ is surjective.
(Hint: with loss of generality assume that $0\in R^n$ is not in $Im(f)$ ).

Definitions:

1. A proper map: a continuos map $f:X \to Y$ ($X,Y$ are topological spaces) is called proper if for all $K \subset Y$ compact, $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.
2. Let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds.
   We say that $y\in N$ is a singular value of $f$ is there is $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ such that $d_xf$ is not surjective, othetwise $y$ is called a regular value of $f$ (i.e. for all $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ , $d_xf$ is surjective).
3. Homotopy:
   Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds, $\partial M=\emptyset$.
   If $f_0, f_1: M\to N$ are smooth, then we say that a smooth map $F:M\times [0,1] \to N$ is a homotopy if  $F(x,i)=f_i(x)$ for $i=0,1$ and $x\in M$.

For (a):
Trial 1: by the contrapositive.
Assume that $|f(x)|$ is bounded so $f$ is bounded too. And so the image of $f$ is contained in a closed ball (in $R^n$) that is a compact set, however the preimage of this ball would be $R^n$ which is not compact (because it is not bounded)?

Trial 2: consider a sequence (in $R^n$) that goes to $\infty$, if its image is bounded inside $U\subset R^n$, we take a compact set $K$ that contains a limit point so tge preimage of $K$ in not compact since it  contains a subsequence of the initial sequence that goes to infinity.
How to write this formally?

For (b):

Let $r_2>r_1>r_0$ , define a homotopy:
$H:S^{n-1}\times [0,1]\to S^{n-1}$ by

$H(x,t)=\phi_{(1-t)r_1+tr_2}\phi_{r_1}$.

So if $t=0$, $H(x,0)=\phi_{ r_1}$ and if $t=1$, $H(x,1)=\phi_{r_2}$
Therefore $H $ is a homotopy (from $\phi_{r_1}$ to $\phi_{r_2}$).
Now using a theorem that states: if $M,N$ are smooth manifolds without boundary and have same dimension and have orientation. If $f_0, f_1$ are smooth, proper and there exists a proper homotopy between them that is a smooth, proper map $F:M\times [0,1] \to N$ which is a homotopy (from $f_0$ to $f_1$), then $\forall$
$y\in N$ a regular value of $f_0, f_1$ ,$deg_y f_0=deg_y f_1$.
In tgis case, $f_0=\phi_{r_1}, f_1=\phi_{r_2}$
Both are maps $S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, they are smooth and proper since $f$ is so.

For (c), I tried to use the theorem:

If $f:M\to N$ is a smooth, proper map where $M, N$ are smooth manifolds without boundary. $M, N$ with same dimensions and have orientations, $N$ is connected.
So if $f$ is not surjective then $deg(f)=0$.
(If $f:M\to N$ is a smooth, proper, non surjective map then $deg (f)=0$).
I also thought about using homotopy here but did not manage to apply it.

Edited:

Part a: let $x_n$ be a sequence with $\|x_n\|\to \infty$ such that {$f(x_n): n$} is bounded. Choose a compact set $K\subset R^n$ to be $\overline {f(x_n):n}$ so it is a bounded and closed set in $R^n$ thus compact. However $f^{-1}(K)=\overline {x_n:n}$ is not compact since it is not bounded.

Part b: Let $r_2>r_1>r_0$ , define a homotopy:
$H:S^{n-1}\times [0,1]\to S^{n-1}$ by

$H(x,t)=\phi_{(1-t)r_1+tr_2}\phi_{r_1}$.

So if $t=0$, $H(x,0)=\phi_{ r_1}$ and if $t=1$, $H(x,1)=\phi_{r_2}$
Therefore $H $ is a homotopy, i.e. $\phi_{r_1}$ and $\phi_{r_2}$ are homotopic. Thus $deg (\phi_r)$ is independent of $r>r_0$. Why can I say that $\phi_r$ is smooth? (And so $H$ is smooth).

Part c: Assume that $f$ is non-surjective with $0$ not in $Im(f)$, then $\phi_r$ is defined for all $r\geq 0$.
By part b, since $\phi_r$ is indepedendent of the choice of $r$ so $deg(\phi_r)=deg(\phi_0)=$deg(constant) $=0$, a contradiction to the assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a): The opposite of $\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty}\|f(x)\|=\infty$ is not “$f$ is bounded”. Rather it is: There is a sequence $x_n$ with $\|x_n\|\to\infty$ such that $\{f(x_n):n\}$ is bounded. Now you can get a contradiction to the compactness similarly as you attempted in Trial 2.

Your proof of (b) is the correct approach, but haven't you learnt a more general theorem about the homotopy invariance of the degree?

The approach to (c) is correct, and it is essentially the only possible approach: You need to use the so-called existence property of the degree (which is also sometimes formulated as part of the so-called additivity property); the homotopy invariance alone is not sufficient. One way to prove that $0$ lies in the image of $f$ is to combine it with the homotopy invariance: Assume by contradiction that $0$ does not lie in the image of $f$. What can you say about $\phi_r$ for $r<r_0$, in particular for $r=0$?

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain how to write a similar explanation to the one I did, but in your symbols ($x_n, f(x_n)$. In b, there is a theorem that says: if $M,N$ are smooth manifolds with same dim, without boundary and have orientation, $N$ is connected then for all $F:M\to N$ a smooth and proper map $deg_y(f)$ is indepedent of the choice of the regular value $y\in N$. I think my approach above (in b) is not complete, can you tell me how to finish it (why $\phi_{r_1},\phi_{r_2}$ smooth and proper) .

Comment: In c if ae assume that $0\in R^n$ , $0\notin Im(f)$, it means that $f$ is not surjective so by the theorem we have $deg(f)=0$ so does it says $deg(\phi_r)=0$ too? Because of how $\phi_r$ is defined in terms of $f$?  A contradiction to the assumption that $deg(\phi_r)\neq 0$.

Comment: Concerning (a), I give one more hint (no complete solution!): You have an unbounded sequence $x_n$ with bounded image sequence $f(x_n)$. You have to show that this cannot happen if $f$ is proper. But properness means that for every compact set $K$ the preimage $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact. Now, given that $f(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence in a Euclidean space, it should be easy to find a compact set $K$ which shows that $f$ cannot be proper.

Comment: Concerning (b): Haven't you learnt a theorem that the degree is invariant under (proper) homotopies or with a compact preimage $h^{-1}(y)$? (There are various formulations of the homotopy invariance property of the degree.)

I mean: not only for regular values $y$; the consideration of regular values is useful for the construction of the degree, but in general one usually just applies the more general theorems which hide these technical details of the construction.

Comment: Concerning (c): Assume by contradiction $0\notin Im(f)$. Then $\phi_r$ is defined for all $r\ge0$, and by the homotopy invariance $\deg(\phi_r)$ is independent of $r$. But for $r=0$, the map $\phi_0$ is constant and thus certainly not onto.

Comment: It is possible to show that $deg(\phi_r)=deg_y(f|_{B_r})$ if $r>0$ is arbitrary (where $y$ is some arbitrary point of $\mathbb R^n$). However, the proof of this fact is deep and requires (among other things) a property about the degree on Cartesian products (because $\phi_r$ and $f$ are defined on manifolds of different dimensions).

Comment: What you mean by the homotopy invariance, is there any theorem relevant to it?  But you are using this for part c (not b?)  You showed that $\phi_0$ is not  surjective, so why $f$ is also not surjective,

Comment: As I mentioned, there are several theorems about homotopy invariance of the degree, the simplest being that if two maps $\phi_r,\phi_0\colon S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ are homotopic, they have the same degree. If $\phi_0$ is not surjective, then $\phi_0$ and thus $\phi_r$ has degree $0$. This contradiction shows that $0$ lies in the image of $f$. To see that every other point lies in the image of $f$ as well, you can argue similarly, using further homotopies.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Väth can you take a look on my edit in the post?

Comment: LGTM. The exercise would be easier for you if you would have learnt more about the degree already. For instance, continuity is enough to define the degree; smoothness is not needed. However, if you take the Euclidean norm, then the norm is a smooth function (except in $0$), because it is the composition of squares and a squareroot (which is smooth outside of $0$), so $\phi_r$ is smooth as a composition of smooth functions.

Comment: Regarding part b, I find a theorem saying: Let $M, N$ be smooth oriented manifolds without boundary, such that $dim M = dim N$, where $N$ is connected. Then The degree is an invariant of proper homotopy, that is if $g: M → N$ is properly homotopic to $f:M\to N$, then $deg f = deg g$. Def: If $f_0, f_1$ are proper, then a proper homotopy is a smooth homotopy which is a proper map. In case it exists, we say that f0, f1 are properly homotopic. In our case why are $\phi_{r_1}, \phi_{r_2}$ and $H$ proper? We are given that $f$ is proper so does it also imply something about $\phi$? @Martin Väth

Comment: Every continuous function defined on a compact set is proper: Preimages of compact sets are closed, hence compact.